# Lighouse @paginator with all records

Tags: graph, laravel-lighthouse

I am using `@paginator` directive on my query and my client wants to get all records of posts from the query. This is my code:

```
posts: [Post!]! @paginate
```

I tested this querys:

```
posts(first:0) {id} #works but don't get all records
posts(first:-1) {id} #error
```

One way was to get all records was to use the value of `total` inside the `paginatorInfo` and make a new query with that value on the `first:`.

```
 posts(first:0) {
   paginatorInfo {
     total
   }
 }
```

For optimization making 2 querys to get all records is very bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach I got was to make a new query (now having two querys for posts with different directives and names) like:

```
allPosts: [Post!]! @all
```

Other approaches but not so clean:

- Set pagination.max_count to null in the config/lighthouse.php and do `(first: 100000000)` (the `int` is 32 bits so has a limit).
- Change the `@paginantor` to a `@field(resolver:)` and do pagination with pure php.